# Increasing Pointer Array Size - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, min-heap

I was working on creating a Min Heap Class (for practice) and it completely works, however, it seems to me that my increase capacity function for the pointer array, which holds the heap array, probably causes a memory leak. (excuse my terrible coding). Below I show my function, constructor, and private member init, however, this isn't how it's actually structured in the code, just like this for convenience for writing the post.

```
int* heap; // init as a private member

MinHeap() {
   this->total_capacity = 10; // init in default constructor
   heap = new int[total_capacity];
}

// if total capacity is reached:
 // creates a larger array and copies all elements over to it
 void ensureExtraCapacity() {
    if (length == total_capacity) {
       total_capacity *= 2;
       int* temp = new int[total_capacity];
       for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
          temp[i] = heap[i];
       heap = temp;
       delete[] temp; // <= this is causing me issues
       cout << "Capacity added." << endl;
    }
 }
```

- Length is a int that keeps track of how many numbers are in the heap

I attempted to delete it, however, it ended up either deleting new numbers from the new array or added two zeros, either way, it's not good.

[with the "delete[] temp"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgngS.png)
[without the "delete[] temp"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7vtM.png)

2 Things:

- I know I can use a life-changing vector but I wanted to use pointer arrays for practice.
- If there is a better way to accomplish this (like using some STL function like copy or std:array, let me know however I still would like an answer to this)

P.S: Sorry if this is a duplicate, I looked around I swear.

P.S: If there are any resources you know of to get better with memory handling and pointers (or even the STL library) please link it as well, thanks!